# Prevent page zoom while allowing wheel scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

Is it possible to prevent scroll wheel page zoom **while allowing page scrolling with the scroll wheel**? Is there a way to perhaps let the scroll event through while preventing the event responsible for the page zoom with `event.preventDefault()`?

For example, this code works nicely to prevent scroll wheel page zoom...

```
window.addEventListener ('wheel', function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault ();
    }
}, false);
```

However, it also prevents scroll wheel page scrolling, and I still want scroll wheel page scrolling while the Ctrl/Shift key is pressed. That is what I am trying to accomplish.

That example code is plain JavaScript, but I am working with jQuery, so if there is a way to simulate a default-looking scroll after preventing the normal wheel scroll event, that would suffice.

**Edit:** I need to be able to scroll the page with the scroll wheel while preventing the page zoom.

Comment: @gaetanoM Nope. I need something different.

Comment: You are right. I saw there a neutralizeZoom  function or on the next answer ....event.view.devicePixelRatio  .... I assume you can use something similar to neutralize zoom and continue.... Can this help you?

Comment: @gaetanoM No, because the zoom prevents the page from scrolling, so even if the zoom can be "neutralized", that wouldn't allow the page to scroll.

Comment: If I understood correctly you need to scroll down/up with ctrl+wheel. What about: prevent default action if ctrlKey  is true (avoid zoom) and trigger a scroll event by yourself?

Comment: I guess you can manually scroll the page with js by xxx amount each time the wheel is triggered. So the result is when you use the wheel when ctrl is pressed, the wheel is not doing anything but the js is scrolling the page. Of course this might not scroll the exact same as the natural wheel scroll, but at least it scrolls while preventing zoom

Comment: That is more or less the exact problem I am having, every method of manually triggering a scroll is different than the default behavior, and it's quite noticeable. Is there perhaps a way to get the number of pixels the scroll normally moves by? cc: @gaetanoM